# With AAD Registered Applications, what can prevent a malicious insider from adding secrets and exploiting them? Redirect URL?

Tags: azure-active-directory

My organization is taking a look at the security of registered applications within Azure Active Directory (AAD) and have concerns around the ability of individuals to add client secrets and certificates for applications that are using the "application permissions" model.  I'm working to help narrow the roles of individuals within the organization to restrict this, but this investigation begged the question of what a malicious insider could do if he or she could add a client secret to this application.

I've looked through the [30 Days of Microsoft Graph blog series](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/announcing-30-days-of-microsoft-graph-blog-series/#), which is excellent, but wanted to clarify what else can be done to prevent an insider from gaining access to the permissions this application would allow.

Does the **redirect URL** itself protect against this kind of scenario, provided the organization retains control of all registered URLs (meaning, for example, that https://localhost isn't registered)?  Based on [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-23-use-case-calling-microsoft-graph-from-a-single-page-application-part-1/) post under Step 3, I assume the answer is yes but wanted to make sure this is the case.

Is it technically correct to say that without the redirect URL being secured/owned by the organization, a malicious insider who could add client secrets could exploit the permissions granted by the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to add a client secret to an app that already has been granted application permissions to something, then this user can use the new secret to get tokens and access those resources as the app.

Redirect URL is not used with application permissions, only delegated permissions.
This is because there are no redirects in the client credentials grant flow, which is used when acquiring a token with app permissions.
It's just an HTTP request.

So you are correct in your assumption that being able to add a new secret to an app that already has permissions can be a security issue.
There are audit logs though, and I believe adding a secret/certificate is logged.